# A moment's question.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let G be a (absolutely) continuous distribution such that
$$\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{2}dG(x)}}<\infty$$
or
$$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}{\left[G^{-}(t)\right]^{2}dt}}<\infty.$$
Suppose $0< z< 1$ and $\gamma >1$. Can we say that
$$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{z}{t^{\gamma}\left[G^{-}(t)\right]^{2}dt}}+\displaystyle{\int_{z}^{1}{(1-t)^{\gamma}\left[G^{-}(t)\right]^{2}dt}}<\infty\ \ \ ?$$

Comment: I am not familiar with $G^-(t)$ notation. Would it be possible to recast the question in the former notation?

Comment: I think $G^-$ means $G^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, Mr Montgomery-Smith. I'll be more especific in future question. Clarification: The notation in my question was used to mean "Generalized Inverse". I didn't put "-1" in the notation because this simbol usually indicates the Classical Inverse. When G is a distribution, it may have Classical Inverse or not, but it always has Generalized Inverse.

Comment: OK.  But I still think my solution works.

Answer (score 2):

Since $[G^{-}(t)]^2 \ge 0$, and $t$ in the integrand is in $[0,1]$, we have that
$$ t^\gamma [G^{-}(t)]^2 \le [G^{-}(t)]^2 \quad\text{and} \quad
(1-t)^\gamma [G^{-}(t)]^2 \le [G^{-}(t)]^2 .$$